# Preparing data for CATPCA

Tags: categorical-data, pca, factor-analysis, ordinal-data

I'm about to run a factor analysis using CATPCA. However, some of my ordinal variables represent positive phenomena (e.g. my neighbourhood is beautiful) with 1 for "strongly agree", 2 for "agree" etc., whereas my other ordinal variables represent negative phenomena (e.g. crime is a problem here) with 1 for "strongly agree", 2 for "agree" etc. Should I swap coding for negative variables to make them comparable with the positive variables and then run the factor analysis?

Comment: That's as you like. This issue does not differ from situation when you are doing usual PCA or FA.

Comment: consider this R package for PCA on categorical variables (which called Multiple Correspondence Analysis by the way): http://factominer.free.fr/classical-methods/multiple-correspondence-analysis.html

Comment: Thanks ttnphns2. I was thinking it should have an effect on CATPCA as factor analysis is based on correlations, and ordering data in ascending or descending order matters?